# Doubts about docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm new with docker, and have some doubts.

In a dev environment (not server), is better to use just one container, with apache, php and mysql for exemple, and use just a docker and a Dockerfile, or is better to use one container for each service, and use docker-compose to do it?
I have made this [here](https://github.com/luizpaulofranz/docker-environments) with docker-compose, but I don't know if it is the best way, seems to me unnecessary complexity, but I'm newb.

I have the following situation, I work with magento, and is a common need to have a clear instalation for isolate modules and test, so I want create my magento 2 docker environment, where have just a clear magento and must have some easy way of put my module files inside, for test, and ons shutdown, the environment backs to clear magento 2 instalation, without my files, what is the best way to get this environemnt?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd certainly recommend using a docker stack (defined in a docker-compose), and not trying to spin up a whole application stack inside a single container. You should have one service per container generally.

I believe what you are looking for in the second part of your question is a deployment orchestration tool. Docker does not replace deployment orchestration, but you can run shell scripts that do application setup in the Dockerfiles that build the containers you use in your stack.

As for access to files inside your containers, I'd look into docker volumes.

Comment: Ok, so I will work with multiple containers, even on my local development environment. Another doubt, to orchestrate the containers, should I use docker-compose or kubernets? And why? Thanks in advance.